# Get Download Progress Percentage In Glide

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` with some items that each item has an `ImageView`.
I'm using `Glide` library to download images and its thumbnail from a URL.
My problem is how can i get image download progress percentage for each item?
(I test [this solution](https://gist.github.com/fbis251/cfa169fd9e1e142e042c) 
but it doesn't work properly in `ListAdapter`.)